# GUI freezes when use ensemble library with two levels of configuration in weka

Tags: java, weka

I'm student I get nice results with weka Unfortunately in the last stage for my experiments 
weka not work I have used ensemble library with success. However when i tried to add a classifier with two levels of configuration (ie a meta-classifier ) the GUI freezes up. I have tried everything but at the end i couldn't  add a meta-classifier into the library. Has anyone help me in this problem?

Weka : 3.7.11 
Java Version : 1.7.0(64 bit) 
OS : Win8
RAM:16GB

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. and it forces me to switch and work with WEKA libraries in java.
I don't have any idea about the bug is in the GUI but i'm sure if you switch to API and use 
WEKA library in JAVA code, your problem will solve.

(and the point which is interesting for me is that your system configuration is very higher than mine, so i think this bug is not related to system configuration).

Comment: thanks for your reply can you help me to explain the step for JAVA code ,  i used GUI  only

Comment: ok, using the java source codes is simple like GUI, you can use [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da6Iq2XV7_Q] or other youtube suggests. these can help you to start using JAVA API of weka as fast as possible.